# how to group sequence of item into square brackets

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

how to group sequence of item into square brackets

for example

List of items

```
cat item.txt
    sn01
    sn02
    sn03
    sn05
    sn07
    sn08
```

Desired output

```
sn[01-03,05,07-08]
```

Comment: What efforts did you make? Show us your attempts

Comment: are the numbers always come in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is same as shown Input_file sample then following may help you in same.

```
awk 'FNR==1{line=$0} {sub(/[a-z]+/,"")} $0-val>1 && val1!=val{out=out?out "," val1"-"val:line"[" val1"-"val;val1=$0} $0-val>1 && val1==val{out=out?out "," val1:out "," val1;val1=$0} {if(FNR==1){sub(/[0-9]+/,"",line);val1=$0};val=$0}END{if(val1!=val){print out "," val1"-"val"]"} else {print out "," val"]"}}'  Input_file
```

Adding non-one liner form of solution too.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  line=$0
}
{
sub(/[a-z]+/,"")
}
$0-val>1 && val1!=val{
  out=out?out "," val1"-"val:line"[" val1"-"val;
  val1=$0
}
$0-val>1 && val1==val{
  out=out?out "," val1:out "," val1;
  val1=$0
}
{
if(FNR==1){
  sub(/[0-9]+/,"",line);
  val1=$0
};
val=$0
}
END{
if(val1!=val){
  print out "," val1"-"val"]"
}
else{
  print out "," val"]"
}
}
'    Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
sn[01-03,05,07-08]
```

Comment: "sn" being static here. it should pick it from the input file. when I given list of items start with "cn". still it picks "sn"

Comment: sn[01-31,50-51,82-85,100-100] also "100" comes twice

Comment: @asokan, could you please check my edit now and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @asokan, glad that it helped you, keep learning and keep sharing, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> "sn" being static here. it should pick it from the input file. when I
>   given list of items start with "cn". still it picks "sn"

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat infile
sn01
sn02
sn03
sn05
sn07
sn08
cn08
cn09
cn10
cn11
cn15
```

when `search='sn'`

```
$ awk -v search='sn' 'function pr(){if(f && l)printf("%s%s",n?",":search"[",f==l?f:f"-"l)}$0!~"^"search{next}{t=$1;sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",t)}f==""{f=l=t;next}t==l+1{l=t;next}{pr();f=l=t;n++}END{pr(); print n?"]":"Nothing matched for keyword :"search}' infile
sn[01-03,05,07-08]
```

when `search='cn'`

```
$ awk -v search='cn' 'function pr(){if(f && l)printf("%s%s",n?",":search"[",f==l?f:f"-"l)}$0!~"^"search{next}{t=$1;sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",t)}f==""{f=l=t;next}t==l+1{l=t;next}{pr();f=l=t;n++}END{pr(); print n?"]":"Nothing matched for keyword :"search}' infile
cn[08-11,15]
```

**Better Readable :**

```
awk -v search='sn' '
                   function pr()
                   {
                       if(f && l)
                         printf("%s%s",n?",":search"[",f==l?f:f"-"l)
                   }
                   $0!~"^"search{ 
                          next 
                   }
                   {
                         t=$1;
                         sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",t)
                   }
                  f==""{
                         f=l=t;
                         next
                   }
                   t==l+1{
                         l=t;
                         next
                   }
                   {
                         pr();
                         f=l=t;
                         n++
                   }
               END{
                         pr(); 
                         print n?"]":"Nothing matched for keyword :"search
                  }' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple **awk** solution

We're aiming to set `LB` and `UB` for each possible range.
Starting from `LB`, the last number in sequence upto which the `common difference` is 1 gives us the `UB`.
If difference is more than `1` print the last range and set `LB` again.

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{ $1=$1; prefix=substr($0,1,2);} {gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$1); a[++i]=$1;} END{ printf prefix"["; LB=UB=prev=a[1]; for(i=1; i<=NR; i++){ if(int(a[i+1])==int(prev+1)) { UB=a[i+1]; prev=UB; } else { if(LB==UB) { printf LB"," } else {delim=(i==NR)? "]" :","; printf LB "-" UB delim; } prev=LB=UB=a[i+1]; }} }' file

sn[01-03,05,07-08]
```

`gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$1)` : This sets all non-digit chars to null. Therefore `$1` ends up with just numbers;

To understand it better :

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{ $1=$1; prefix=substr($0,1,2); } {gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$1); a[++i]=$1;} 
    END
    { 
        printf prefix"["; LB=UB=prev=a[1]; 

        for(i=1; i<=NR; i++)
        { 
            if(int(a[i+1])==int(prev+1)) 
            { 
                UB=a[i+1]; 
                prev=UB; } 

            else 
            { 
                if(LB==UB) 
                { 
                    printf LB"," 
                } 

                else 
                {   
                    delim=(i==NR)? "]" :","; 
                    printf LB "-" UB delim; 
                } 

                prev=LB=UB=a[i+1]; 
            }
        } 
    }' file
```

Comment: yeah makes sense!! (y) Thanks Akshay. Let me update it.

Answer (score 0):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk '{ v=substr($0,3) }NR==1{ pfx=substr($0,1,2); r=a=v; next }
     { diff=v-a; if(diff>1) { r=r ((a==last)? ",":"-"a",")v; last=v } a=v }
     END{ if(diff==1) r=r"-"v; print pfx"["r"]" }' file
```

The output:

```
sn[01-03,05,07-08]
```